# Reading New Email Using UIDs with imap_tools

Tags: python, imap-tools

I have been scraping emails from a shared mailbox using imap_tools. The script checks the mailbox as frequently as possible and I use `msgs = client.fetch(AND(seen=False))` to check only unread emails.

Even though I check frequently sometimes emails are not scraped because another user has already opened the email.

Is there another way of checking for new emails, eg using UIDs?

Comment: Get rid of the seen=false and keep track of which ones you’ve already processed locally?

Answer (score 0):

Emails has message-id header, it is constant.